# How can I enable Pascal casing by default when using Jackson JSON in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, naming-conventions, jackson

I have a project that uses Spring MVC to create and handle multiple REST endpoints. I'm currently working on using Jackson to automatically handle the seralization/deserialization of JSON using the `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` annotations.

I have gotten Jackson working, so I've got a starting point. My problem is that our old serialization was done manually and used Pascal casing instead of Camel casing ("MyVariable" instead of "myVariable"), and Jackson does Camel casing by default.

I know that I can manually change the name for a variable using `@JsonProperty`. That being said, I do not consider adding `@JsonProperty` to all of my variables to be a viable long-term solution.

Is there a way to make Jackson use Pascal casing when serializing and deserializing other than using the `@JsonProperty` annotation?

EDIT: It looks like there's not a clean way to do this externally. A couple people have suggested overriding different classes as a way to accomplish my goal. I'm open to suggestions on what I can override that will change the casing. At the moment I have made a custom ObjectMapper that sets some properties I want (namely `Inclusion.NON_NULL`). I haven't found any place yet that would let me change the casing behavior. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think so, Jackson will always use the java-style name

Comment: Off the cuff, can you extend the Jackson class(es) and change the naming convention that way?

Comment: You can override some pieces (AnnotationIntrospector, BeanSerializerFactory) to do that. But there isn't yet a clean externalized way to add naming strategies (that has been requested by multiple users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by overriding the (de)serializers. For those interested, here's how you can do it yourself:

Step 1. Extend `BeanSerializerFactory`.

Override the `_constructWriter(SerializationConfig config, TypeBindings typeContext, PropertyBuilder pb, boolean staticTyping, String name, AnnotatedMember propertyMember)` method. Inside that method, modify `name` in any way you see fit. To implement Pascal casing, I used this line: `String formattedName = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);`. After modifying `name`, call `super._constructWriter`.

Step 2. Extend `BeanDeserializationFactory`.

Override the `constructSettableProperty(DeserializationConfig config, BasicBeanDescription beanDesc, String name, AnnotatedMethod setter)` method. Do the same thing with the `name` parameter that you did inside your custom `BeanSerializerFactory`.

Step 3. Create an `ObjectMapper`.

Set the serializer factory to be your custom bean serializer factory. Set the deserializer provider (I used this line: `objectMapper.setDeserializerProvider(new StdDeserializerProvider(new CustomJacksonBeanDeserializerFactory()))`).

That's it. The `ObjectMapper` you created will use your new naming scheme when serializing or deserializing JSON.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_448.html
If you can wait for 1.8 it will be included there.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, there is a [Jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-178) to support pluggable strategies; voting for it might help convince developers to add support. As I mentioned in the comment, it is possible to override internal behavior, but it is not a simple thing to do.