# Jackson serialise fields as uppercase?

Tags: json, jackson

My object gets serialised as {name="nyname" ....}, however, I require all keys to be start with uppercase, ie. {Name="myname",.....}   how can I do that with Jackson ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and posted about it earlier. I solved it here:
[How can I enable Pascal casing by default when using Jackson JSON in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670116/how-can-i-enable-pascal-casing-by-default-when-using-jackson-json-in-spring-mvc)

If you're not using Spring, the answer would be similar. You'll still need a custom (de)serializer, and you'd just need to wire it in to your program in the manner you choose.

Comment: As mentioned in the question @bhilstrom referenced, the current Jackson release now allows custom PropertyNamingStrategy implementations.